# How to update a document by ID using Firebase Modular SDK (V9)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

This code creates a new document every time the user logs in but my task is to update existing same user ID document if it exists else create a new one. How can I do that in V9 Firebase?

Current Code

```
setDoc(
  query(collectionRef),
  //     db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set(

  {
    email: user.email,
    lastSeen: serverTimestamp(),
    photoURL: user.photoURL
  }, {
    merge: true
  }
);
```

Old Code that access document UID:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter in `setDoc()` should be [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference):

```
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"

const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);

setDoc(docRef, {
  email: user.email,
  lastSeen: serverTimestamp(),
  photoURL: user.photoURL
}, {
  merge: true
}).then(() => console.log("Document updated"));
```

Comment: What is the difference between updateDoc and setDoc ? I was trying to use `updateDoc` but it threw error saying `No Document to update` and with `setDoc` its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, You can also use updateDoc().

```js
import {
  doc,
  updateDoc
} from "firebase/firestore"

update(doc(db, "users", user.uid, {
  email: user.email,
  lastSeen: serverTimestamp(),
  photoURL: user.photoURL
}).then(() => console.log("Document updated"));
```